# Infer a tuple type from an array with values of a known type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write code that achieves the following:

Imagine I have code elsewhere that defines `class Schema<T extends string|number|boolean>`,

Now let's say I write

```
const superSchema = [
    new Schema<string>(),
    new Schema<number>(),
    new Schema<boolean>(),
    new Schema<number>()
]
```

I want to define a type called `SuperSchemaInfer` such that `SuperSchemaInfer<typeof superSchema>` is equal to `[string, number, boolean, number]`.

How can I do this? I think it should be possible since Zod does something similar.

So far I have written some code, but all I was able to get was `SuperSchemaInfer<typeof superSchema>` equal to `(string|number|boolean)[]`.

Here is my code so far:

```
type SupportedTypes = string | number | boolean

type SchemaArray = Array<Schema<SupportedTypes>>

type SchemaArrayInfer<S extends SchemaArray> = {
    [K in keyof S]: S[K] extends Schema<infer U> ? U : never
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with the type you wrote, but with the type you input

```
const superSchema = [
    // ^?
    // const superSchema: (Schema<string> | Schema<number> | Schema<boolean>)[]
    new Schema<string>(),
    new Schema<number>(),
    new Schema<boolean>(),
    new Schema<number>()
]
```

All you need to fix this is to mark array `as const` and change generic to support `ReadonlyArray`

```
type SchemaArrayInfer<S extends readonly Schema<string | number | boolean>[]> = {
    [K in keyof S]: S[K] extends Schema<infer U> ? U : never
}
const superSchema = [
    // ^?
    // const superSchema: (Schema<string> | Schema<number> | Schema<boolean>)[]
    new Schema<string>(),
    new Schema<number>(),
    new Schema<boolean>(),
    new Schema<number>()
] as const
type R = SchemaArrayInfer<typeof superSchema>
//   ^?
// type R = readonly [string, number, boolean, number]
```

Comment: I see now. Is it possible to abstract out `as const` into the `SuperSchemaInfer` definition?

Comment: @MichaelSohnen No, it isn't. It's a different story however, if you want to use something like `schemaFunction([ /* schemas */ ])`.

Comment: @pink I am fine with the function syntax you just mentioned. Can you link me to an article or example of how to do that?